# Specs2 on OSX - error: object specs2 is not a member of package org

Tags: macos, scala, sbt, specs2

I am trying to run some Scala code on my OSX machine and keep on getting an error that says

`error: object specs2 is not a member of package org`

I have version 2.9.1-1 of Scala installed.
I am also using verison 0.7.7 of sbt

My build.sbt file looks like this

```
name := "Comp-338-Web-App"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.7",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.8.2" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.9.0",
  "org.hamcrest" % "hamcrest-all" % "1.1"
)

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
              "releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases")
```

I've tried a bunch of different things but can't get it to run the test correctly.

Any advice?

Let me know if you need more information about the settings on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution looks simple: Please use the latest release of sbt, currently 0.11.2.

The version 0.7.x you are using does not know how to use *build.sbt*, which was only introduced in sbt 0.9 or so.

Comment: What if I'm using gradle?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to moving to sbt 0.11.2 I recommend going to [full configuration](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example) even though the author recommends using .sbt descriptor for the majority of tasks, and use .scala descriptor only if you cannot achieve something with .sbt syntax or use subprojects (I do for all of my projects to clearly separate different parts of application).

Below is the sample project setup that I use for the project I've just started so it only has specs2 dependency:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "net.batyuk"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.1"
  val buildVersion = "0.1"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(organization := buildOrganization,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion,
    version := buildVersion)
}

object Resolvers {
  val typesafeRepo = "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
  val sonatypeRepo = "Sonatype Releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"

  val scalaResolvers = Seq(typesafeRepo, sonatypeRepo)
}

object Dependencies {
  val specs2Version = "1.8.2"

  val specs2 = "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % specs2Version
}

object IdefixBuild extends Build {

  import Resolvers._
  import Dependencies._
  import BuildSettings._

  val commonDeps = Seq(specs2)

  lazy val idefix = Project("idefix", file("."), settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(resolvers := scalaResolvers,
                                                                                     libraryDependencies := commonDeps))
}
```